# Mongodb narrow down $group to specific ID

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Have a collection of documents looking like this:

```
{
   _id: %%ID%%,
   category: %%CATEGORY_ID%%
   theory: %%THEORY_ID%%
}
```

I am trying to count the amount of categories for specific theory (one person may classify theory A as AA, and another person may classify theory A as AB - thats the general idea)

```
{
    $group: {
       "_id": "$category",
       "count": { "$sum": 1 }
   }       
}
```

which returns:

```
[
  { _id: 5f47e3be91e24c35c1081c36, count: 1 },
  { _id: 5f47b9341c56712da1d14b9e, count: 2 },
  { _id: 5f47b9821c56712da1d14ba4, count: 1 },
  { _id: 5f47b95e1c56712da1d14ba2, count: 1 },
  { _id: 5f47e44d91e24c35c1081c37, count: 2 },
  { _id: 5f47b94a1c56712da1d14b9f, count: 2 }
]
```

How can narrow it down to one specific theory. I am trying to run smth like

```
$match: { 
    "theory": %%THEORY_ID_I_WANT_TO_COUNT_FOR%% // or "theory": { $eq: %%THEORY_ID_I_WANT_TO_COUNT_FOR%% }
},
$group: { ... }
```

But it results in `"Error: Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators"`

Comment: Won't `db.collection.aggregate( [ { $match: { "theory": %%THEORY_ID_I_WANT_TO_COUNT_FOR%% } }, { $group: { "_id": "$category", "count": { $sum: 1 } } } ] )` work?

Comment: You probably mistyped something. Add a complete query you are sending with valid syntax (%% is not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using it wrong way, every pipeline must be inside in a separate object, try this,

```
  { $match: { "theory": %%THEORY_ID_I_WANT_TO_COUNT_FOR%% } },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": "$category",
      "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zZstIeEEIY9)